# How to list Items by ItemOrder defined in a separate table? MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to order Items by Item Order defined by user entry on a different page. 
I have a table of Items and a **separate** table Item Orders linked to an Item.
I also have a **separate** table for ItemCategories.
These three tables are all related appropriately.

Different surveys have a specific project than can have multiple items that need to be displayed in the user defined order.

Example:

```
          Project 1                    |              Project 2 
ItemOrder   Item        ItemCategory   |ItemOrder   Item       ItemCategory 
1           Item a      CatA           |8           Item a     CatA
3           Item b      CatB           |7           Item b     CatB
4           Item c      CatC           |5           Item c     CatC
2           Item d      CatD           |4           Item d     CatD
5           Item e      CatE           |6           Item e     CatD
8           Item f      CatF           |1           Item f     CatF
6           Item g      CatG           |3           Item g     CatG
7           Item h      CatH           |2           Item h     CatH
```

I am not sure how to display everything as a list of Item and Category by Project based on the ItemOrder.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Survey(int SurveyId) {
  var model = new SurveyViewModel(SurveyId);
  return View(model);
}
```

Model:

```
public class SurveyViewModel {
  public Survey Survey {get; set;}
  public int SurveyId {get; set;}
  public List<Project> Projects {get; set;}
  public List<OrderedItem> OrderedItems {get; set;}
}

public class OrderedItem {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Order {get; set;}
  public string Category {get; set;}
  public string ItemText {get; set;}
}

public SurveyViewModel(int SurveyId) {
  using (var db = new SurveyContext()) {
   Projects = db.Projects.Include("Items")
                         .Include("Items.Category")
                         .Where(s => s.SurveyId == SurveyId).ToList();

   var Items = from s in Surveys
               from i in s.Project.Items
               from io in i.ItemOrders
               where s.Id == 1
               orderby io.ItemOrder
               select new OrderedItem {
               Id = i.Id,
               Category = i.Category.Category,
               Order = io.Order,
               ItemText = i.Text.Text
               }).Distinct();

//NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE TO POPULATE THE LIST TO PASS TO MY VIEW...
//THIS IS NULL...
   OrderedItems = OrderedItems.ToList(); //?????
  }
}
```

View:

```
@model xxxx.Models.SurveyViewModel
  //Not sure what to do here either...
  @foreach (var item in Model.Survey.Project.Items) {
    @item.Text.Text //???
  }
```

Please help, I think I am mostly there but I am having trouble. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which Model is your view expecting? edit: nvm, I see it's SurveyViewModel.

I am struggling to understand the question though.What type is Model.Survey.Project.Items?

Comment: My question is just how would I list the Items in order by Item Order. I have 10 items each with a specific order number. How would I order them?

Comment: So you want a list of all Items for a given Survey, ordered by the Item's ItemOrder property?

Comment: Yep exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mix your data access code inside your viewmodels. Keep them lean and flat.

```
public class SurveyViewModel {
  public Survey Survey {get; set;}
  public int SurveyId {get; set;}
  public List<Project> Projects {get; set;}
  public List<OrderedItem> OrderedItems {get; set;}
}

public class OrderedItem {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Order {get; set;}
  public string Category {get; set;}
  public string ItemText {get; set;}
}
```

And in your action method, load data to it

```
public ActionResult Survey(int SurveyId) 
{
  var vm = new SurveyViewModel();

     using (var db = new SurveyContext())
     {
         vm.Projects = db.Projects.Include("Items")
                         .Include("Items.Category")
                         .Where(s => s.SurveyId == SurveyId).ToList();

         vm.OrderedItems  = from s in Surveys
                              from i in s.Project.Items
                              from io in i.ItemOrders
                              where s.Id == SurveyId
                              orderby io.ItemOrder
                           select new OrderedItem {
                                Id = i.Id,
                                Category = i.Category.Category,
                                Order = io.Order,
                                ItemText = i.Text.Text
                              }).Distinct().ToList();
     }
     return View(vm);
}
```

You may also move your db access code to another layer if you want to make your controllers lean.

Your razor view will be

```
@model SurveyViewModel
<h2>Ordered Items </h2>
@foreach(var p in Model.OrderedItems )
{
  <p>@p.Category</p> 
  <p>@p.Order</p> 
}
<h2>Projects</h2>
@foreach(var proj in Model.Projects)
{
  <p>@proj.Name</p>      
}
```

Comment: I contract a Microsoft licensed guru for MVC and he writes the code the way I have it above. 

I should ask him why he does it since from everything I've learned they should be separated.

Thank you for your help, you answer helped me get to where I needed to, I was close!